# Using Xcode v15 to test and debug an app on my physical device (iOS 17) but I'm getting a SIGABRT error 0__abort_with_payload

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use Xcode v15  run an app on my physical device (iOS 17) and I'm getting a SIGABRT error in 0__abort_with_payload. This was working perfectly before I updated iOS and Xcode.

I tried removing the app first from the device, and got the same result. I also tried with the Simulator, and the app crashed, but this time the 0__abort_with_payload file did not pop up with the SIGABRT error

I see a [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77047408/swiftdata-0-abort-with-payload)

Seems like a product bug? Any help or patch is appreciated!

- Tried reinstalling Xcode
- Tried debugging my app
- Tried searching apple developer forums and stack-exchange
- Tried Using a different device (same error)
- I tried removing the app from my device before building and installing. I got the same SIGABRT response.
- I was running iOS 16.4 on the previous version of Xcode, on a physical device before the upgrades, and it was working.
- Tried running the simulator with iOS 16.4 with Xcode 15, and the app crashes as soon as I run it, but this time without the SIGABRT displaying.

I'm running react-native, and building the iOS app in the ios folder in my react-native project by opening the project_name.xcworkspace file in Xcode.
Here is a snippet of the code used to start up Metro:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-native start

                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
                  ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
                 ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
                 ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
                  ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


                Welcome to Metro v0.73.9
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info React Native v0.72.5 is now available (your project is running on v0.71.8).
```

Here is the 0__abort_with_payload file that pops up in Xcode when I run the app on iOS 17 with the `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`:
    0x1e40db3b0 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1e40db3b4 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1e40db3b8 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1e40db3d8               ; <+40>
    0x1e40db3bc <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x1e40db3c0 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1e40db3c4 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1e40db3c8 <+24>: bl     0x1e40d07cc               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1e40db3cc <+28>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1e40db3d0 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1e40db3d4 <+36>: retab  
    0x1e40db3d8 <+40>: ret
```

and another tab named '12 start' is open with the `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error on this snippet:

```
    0x1bfd0fc04 <+1784>: mov    x1, #0x0
    0x1bfd0fc08 <+1788>: bl     0x1bfd45f70               ; dyld3::MachOFile::isSimulatorPlatform(dyld3::Platform, dyld3::Platform*)
    0x1bfd0fc0c <+1792>: tbnz   w0, #0x0, 0x1bfd0fc20     ; <+1812>
    0x1bfd0fc10 <+1796>: ldr    x1, [x19, #0x10]
    0x1bfd0fc14 <+1800>: add    x2, sp, #0xd0
    0x1bfd0fc18 <+1804>: mov    x0, x21
    0x1bfd0fc1c <+1808>: bl     0x1bfd26154               ; dyld4::ExternallyViewableState::commit(lsl::Allocator&, lsl::Allocator&)
    0x1bfd0fc20 <+1812>: adrp   x1, -5
    0x1bfd0fc24 <+1816>: add    x1, x1, #0x0
    0x1bfd0fc28 <+1820>: mov    x0, x19
    0x1bfd0fc2c <+1824>: bl     0x1bfd0fe58               ; dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)
->  0x1bfd0fc30 <+1828>: mov    x20, x0
    0x1bfd0fc34 <+1832>: add    x0, sp, #0xd0
    0x1bfd0fc38 <+1836>: bl     0x1bfd2e724               ; lsl::EphemeralAllocator::~EphemeralAllocator()
    0x1bfd0fc3c <+1840>: ldrb   w8, [sp, #0x31]
    0x1bfd0fc40 <+1844>: cbnz   w8, 0x1bfd0fca8           ; <+1948>
    0x1bfd0fc44 <+1848>: ldrb   w8, [sp, #0x30]
    0x1bfd0fc48 <+1852>: cbnz   w8, 0x1bfd0fd30           ; <+2084>
```

and the status at the top right of Xcode says `Paused Flash on Max`
with Flash being the name of the app, and Max being the name of the physical device.

Lastly, [this medium post](https://ivan-ugrin.medium.com/using-xcode-14-with-ios-17-simulator-d74cbc03da4d) seems to give a solution if I downgrade to Xcode 14, but it has not worked on my Mac M1... maybe I'm doing something wrong?

***EDIT: I cannot use Xcode 14 with macOS Sonoma, Sonoma requires Xcode v15 and above.